# Is there any solution for getting item of media queue at nay index?

Tags: chromecast

I am using google chrome cast feature for my iOS App. I am getting an issue with live chrome cast id. I am not able to get media Queue list or It is also not providing the item at any index while I have added 5 item (video) in queue.

Ex : I am using code like this : remotemediaCient.mediaQueue.item(at: UInt(i)) // where i is index number
It is giving me nil in every case.

Please provide me  solution. Thanks

Comment: Have you checked this [github post](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/cast-videos-ios/blob/master/app-done/Classes/MediaViewController.m) using `MediaViewController`?

Comment: Thanks Jess for your response. I have checked it already but I am getting issue when I am using live chrome cast id . It is working fine with sample id. I am not able to view all the added video in queue because remotemediaCient.mediaStatus!.queueItemCount is not giving me more than 3 result at a time.